# Trying to Search a column in a CSV and then return the row associated with that column in Python

Tags: python, csv, search

I am trying to create a piece of code that takes user input in the form of a number and uses that user input to search a specific column in the CSV file and then return teh row associated with that column.

CSV file looks like (Sightings,x and y are the column names I was to search the sightings column):

```
sightings = 1, x = 7, y = 60.
         sightings = 2, x = 12, y = 64.
         sightings = 3, x = 14, y = 66.
         sightings = 4, x = 14, y = 57.
         sightings = 5, x = 17, y = 55.
         sightings = 6, x = 22, y = 58.
         sightings = 7, x = 23, y = 62.
         sightings = 7, x = 23, y = 62.
```

and the code that I have at the moment looks like this:

```
import csv

with open('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/Locations.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are{", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t sightings = {row[0]}, x = {row[1]}, y = {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

At the moment it only prints out the 3 rows and I can't figure out where to progress from here any help is greately appreciated

Answer (score 0):

this question has been solved:

```
#allows user input to select a column and then select a value from that column
data = pd.read_csv('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/Locations.csv')
rowcol = 0 #the colum that is being searched is column 0
row1 = int(input("Enter Number: ")) #enter in your first point on the map Eg 15
row2 = int(input("Enter Number: ")) #enter in your 2nd point on the graph eg 18
result = data.iloc[[row1, row2]]
```